# How to disable set -e for an individual command?

Tags: bash

The set -e command makes a bash script fail immediately when any command returns an non-zero exit code.

1. Is there an easy and elegant way to disable this behaviour for an individual command within a script?
2. At which places is this functionality documented in the Bash Reference Manual (http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the the "exit immediately shell option" applies or is ignored depends on the context of the executed command (see [Bash Reference Manual section on the Set Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin) - thanks to Arkadiusz Drabczyk).

Especially, the option is ignored if a command is part of the test in an if statement. Therefore it is possible to execute a command and check for its success or failure within an "exit immediately context" using an if statement like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# Uncomment next line to see set -e effect:
#blubb

if blubb; then
  echo "Command blubb was succesful."
else 
  echo "Command blubb failed. Exit code: $?"
fi
echo "Script exited normally."
```

It is possible to omit the "then" statement and use fewer lines:

```
if blubb; then :;
else echo "Command blubb failed. Exit code: $?"; fi
```

Comment: Another, even shorter, way to write the short form is: `blubb || echo "Command blubb failed. Exit code: $?"`

Answer (score 62):

1. Something like this:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   set -e
   echo hi

   # disable exitting on error temporarily
   set +e
   aoeuidhtn
   echo next line

   # bring it back
   set -e
   ao

   echo next line
   ```

   Run:

   ```
   $ ./test.sh
   hi
   ./test.sh: line 7: aoeuidhtn: command not found
   next line
   ./test.sh: line 11: ao: command not found
   ```
2. It's described in `set` builtin help:

   ```
   $ type set
   set is a shell builtin
   $ help set
   (...)
   Using + rather than - causes these flags to be turned off.
   ```

The same is documented here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin.

Comment: Thanks! I found another possibility:  #!/bin/bash  

set -e  

# Uncomment next line to see set -e effect:  
#blubb  

if blubb; then  
  echo "Command blubb was succesful."  
else  
  echo "Command blubb failed. Exit code: $?"  
fi  
echo normal script exit

Comment: This has a side-effect though. If the whole script doesn't have `set -e` on it (e.g. depends on execution context, like a command line param to `bash`, decided by the user), then this will force-fully, always, in every context, enable `set -e` after the "bad" command.

Answer (score 38):

An alternative to unsetting the bail on error would be to force a success no matter what.  You can do something like this:

```
cmd_to_run || true
```

That will return 0 (true), so the set -e shouldn't be triggered

Comment: `faulty_cmd || :` is another popular idiom for this. (The `:` is a command synonymous to `true`).

Comment: @ulidtko - interesting.  Led me down the rabbit hole to find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin to get the history on true vs. :

Comment: Really nice solution with a caveat: if you need the exit code, you can't use this.

Comment: @TWiStErRob Can't one use parentheses for getting the exit code? Smth like `(CODE=cmd_to_run) || true`

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś `CODE=cmd_to_run` will just assign `"cmd_to_run"`, so `echo $CODE` outputs `cmd_to_run`.

Comment: Please don't use `:`. You're saving 3 characters but making it much harder to understand.

Answer (score 31):

If you are trying to catch the return/error code (function or fork), this works:

```
function xyz {
    return 2
}

xyz && RC=$? || RC=$?
```

Comment: Oh this one is clever.  Couldn't find a way to use `set -e` and still grab the rc.  Closest I came was putting the cmd in an if statement... which i guess this is.   Much shorter though! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Another approach, which I find fairly straightforward (and applies to other `set` options in addition to `-e`):

Make use of `$-` to restore settings.

For example:

```
oldopt=$-
set +e
# now '-e' is definitely disabled.
# do some stuff...

# Restore things back to how they were
set -$oldopt
```

Though for `-e` specifically, the options others have mentined (`|| true` or "put inside an `if`") may be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

I like to start subshell if want to change something temporarily. 
Below command demonstrates that first bad_command is ignored and second aborts execution.

```
bash -c 'set -e ;\
( set +e; bad_command ; echo still here ) ;\
echo even here ; \
bad_command ; \
echo but not here;'
```

Comment: This is a really clean way of doing it, no side effects like (+e/-e pair on the same level), no operator hacking (`&&`/`||`), just a nice sub-shell with local state. 

Answer (score 0):

I actually had a similar question recently (though I didn't post, I got around to it), and, from what I can see, it seems like just using set +e before the command and set -e afterward works most elegantly. Here's an example, grabbing the response of the command and not letting the error throw it away.

```
#!/bin/sh

args=""
for argcol in $*
do
    args="${args} ${argcol}"
done
fortunevar=""
fortfail=""
{
    set +e
    fortunevar=`fortune $args`
    fortfail=$?
    set -e
} &> /dev/null
if [ $fortfail == 0 ]
then
    echo ${fortunevar}
    say ${fortunevar}
else
    echo misfortune: an illegal option was detected!
    echo misfortune: usage: misfortune [-afilosw] [-m pattern][ [#%] file/directory/all]
fi
```

This grabs the output of 'fortune', checking its exit status, and echoes and says it. I think this is what you were asking for, or at least something similar? Anyway, hope this helps.

Comment: To clarify, the bit in curly parentheticals being redirected to /dev/null is what you're after, I believe. It makes the command have no ouput and checks its error status without exiting the program.